# Google calendar and Oauth2 workflow is confusing

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I have a web app for a client that displays a calendar for users to click on and schedule an appointment. His calendar needs to be connected 24/7. No user needs to log on or use Oauth. The users simply select a date and time and the event is created. I have everything working as far as getting the calendar and sending events. The problems are with the token and understanding internal vs external in this context.

Problems:

1.When reading the docs, I find it hard to understand if this is an internal or external app. Only the internal client needs to sign on to provide the calendar. But the people who are "setting the events" are the users.

2.The token expires after 7days. Per their docs "Refresh tokens may stop working after they are granted, either because: ... The application has a status of 'Testing' and the consent screen is configured for an external user type, causing the token to expire in 7 days". They provide nothing in this section on if its out of 'Testing', if this will continue to be a problem or not.

Questions:

When it comes to the consent screen, what do I do here for deployment? I deploy, log on once with his account and then work on refreshing the tokens over and over? Or once its not in 'Testing' I wont have to worry about this?

If that is what I need to do, the current refresh token expires within 7days. Do I just write a loop after that time is near expiring to send for another token?

Or have I been doing the wrong method this whole time and this app needs a service account and not use Oauth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.When reading the docs, I find it hard to understand if this is an internal or external app. Only the internal client needs to sign on to provide the calendar. But the people who are "setting the events" are the users.

Internal means google workspace. Within that domain only.  So you could have an internal app that would only work for users within your workspace domain it would not work for standard gmail users.

> 2.The token expires after 7days. Per their docs "Refresh tokens may stop working after they are granted, either because: ... The application has a status of 'Testing' and the consent screen is configured for an external user type, causing the token to expire in 7 days". They provide nothing in this section on if its out of 'Testing', if this will continue to be a problem or not.

Just set it to production then your access tokens will be good for more then seven days.

[image]

> When it comes to the consent screen, what do I do here for deployment? I deploy, log on once with his account and then work on refreshing the tokens over and over? Or once its not in 'Testing' I wont have to worry about this?

You will need to authorize the app again in order to get a new refresh token. Every week basicly.

> If that is what I need to do, the current refresh token expires within 7days. Do I just write a loop after that time is near expiring to send for another token?

This is a manual process a user will need to login to the google account and authorize the app again.

> Or have I been doing the wrong method this whole time and this app needs a service account and not use Oauth?

Google calendar only supports service account if it is being used with Google workspace accounts.  If this is a workspace account then yes you should be using service account authorization its much easer.

Comment: If its in production, will I still need to authorize the app every week? If so, is there a way to only sign in once and never have to again? Or is that only for a service account?

Comment: If its set to production in google cloud console under the oauth2 consent screen it should not be expiring after a week.   If it is you may need to apply for verification.   Service accounts is the only way to authorize to an account without user interaction.